# BigQuery giving inconsistent results

Tags: google-bigquery

I having massive issues with BigQuery.  I have a daily job that runs on a VM in compute engine which occasionally generates tables far too small to be correct.  Rerunning usually fixes the issue but this started happening more and more frequently so I'm investigating it.

Yesterday I found a completed job that gave me the correct results when it ran on the VM.  I re-ran it in the BQ front end, it returned around 10% of the rows it should.  I re-ran it 3 more times and every time it was wrong.  I ran it today and it's now correct!

I have caching turned off.  The source tables have never changed. The query is quite chunky, it processes around 50Gb and uses UDF but it never fails.

What is causing these inconsistencies??  Could I be hitting some resource limit that doesn't cause failure?

Thank you

```
SELECT
  _a.Date Date,
  _d.Site Site,
  _a.Product Product,
  _a.AdUnitId AdUnitId,
  _a.advertiserId AdvertiserId,
  _a.OrderId OrderId,
  _a.LineItemId LineItemId,
  _a.CreativeId CreativeId,
  _a.Country Country,
  _a.CreativeSize CreativeSize,
  _a.RequestedAdUnitSizes RequestedAdUnitSizes,
  _a.Format Format,
  _a.OOP OOP,
  _a.Mode Mode,
  REPLACE(_a.PageType,'%2c',' ') PageType,
  IF(_a.PageType CONTAINS 'gallery',TRUE,FALSE) IsGallery,
  _a.Placement Placement,
  _a.Position Position,
  _a.IsCompanion IsCompanion,
  IF(_a.DeviceCategory CONTAINS 'Mobile','Mobile', _a.DeviceCategory) DeviceCategory,
  SUM(IF(_a.LineItemId=0,1,0)) UnfilledImpressions,
  SUM(IF(NOT _a.Product='Ad Server',INTEGER(_a.RowCount),IF(NOT _a.LineItemId=0,INTEGER(_a.RowCount),0))) TotalImpressions,
  SUM(_a.ActiveViewEligibleImpressions) ActiveViewEligibleImpressions,
  SUM(_b.MeasurableImpressions) + (SUM(_a.ActiveViewEligibleImpressions) - SUM(_b.NonMeasurableImpressions) - SUM(_b.ViewableImpressions)) MeasurableImpressions,
  SUM(_b.ViewableImpressions) ViewableImpressions,
  SUM(_c.RowCount) Clicks
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT( IFNULL(Date,''),IFNULL(STRING(TimeUsec),''),IFNULL(Product,''),IFNULL(STRING(AdUnitId),''),IFNULL(STRING(AdvertiserId),''),IFNULL(STRING(OrderId),''),IFNULL(STRING(LineItemId),''),IFNULL(STRING(CreativeId),''),IFNULL(Country,''),IFNULL(CreativeSize,''),IFNULL(RequestedAdUnitSizes,''),IFNULL(Format,''),IFNULL(OOP,''),IFNULL(Mode,''),IFNULL(PageType,''),IFNULL(Placement,''),IFNULL(Position,''),IFNULL(STRING(IsCompanion),''),IFNULL(DeviceCategory,'')) key,
    Date,
    Product,
    AdUnitId,
    AdvertiserId,
    OrderId,
    LineItemId,
    CreativeId,
    Country,
    CreativeSize,
    RequestedAdUnitSizes,
    Format,
    OOP,
    Mode,
    PageType,
    Placement,
    Position,
    IsCompanion,
    DeviceCategory,
    COUNT(*) RowCount,
    SUM(IF(ActiveViewEligibleImpression='Y',1,0)) ActiveViewEligibleImpressions,
    SUM(IF(NOT ActiveViewEligibleImpression='Y',1,0)) NonActiveViewEligibleImpressions
  FROM
    dfpReaderImpressions(
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkImpressions_319223_20161021],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkBackfillImpressions_319223_20161021],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkImpressions_319223_20161022],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkBackfillImpressions_319223_20161022])
  WHERE
    REPLACE(Date,'-','')='20161021'
  GROUP EACH BY
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 ) _a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    CONCAT( IFNULL(Date,''),IFNULL(STRING(TimeUsec),''),IFNULL(Product,''),IFNULL(STRING(AdUnitId),''),IFNULL(STRING(AdvertiserId),''),IFNULL(STRING(OrderId),''),IFNULL(STRING(LineItemId),''),IFNULL(STRING(CreativeId),''),IFNULL(Country,''),IFNULL(CreativeSize,''),IFNULL(RequestedAdUnitSizes,''),IFNULL(Format,''),IFNULL(OOP,''),IFNULL(Mode,''),IFNULL(PageType,''),IFNULL(Placement,''),IFNULL(Position,''),IFNULL(STRING(IsCompanion),''),IFNULL(DeviceCategory,'')) key,
    SUM(IF(MeasurableImpression='Y',1,0)) MeasurableImpressions,
    SUM(IF(NOT MeasurableImpression='Y',1,0)) NonMeasurableImpressions,
    SUM(IF(ViewableImpression='Y',1,0)) ViewableImpressions,
    SUM(IF(NOT ViewableImpression='Y',1,0)) NonViewableImpressions
  FROM
    dfpReaderActiveViews(
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkActiveViews_319223_20161021],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkBackfillActiveViews_319223_20161021],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkActiveViews_319223_20161022],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkBackfillActiveViews_319223_20161022])
  WHERE
    REPLACE(Date,'-','')='20161021'
  GROUP EACH BY
    1 ) _b
ON
  _a.key = _b.key
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    CONCAT( IFNULL(Date,''),IFNULL(STRING(TimeUsec),''),IFNULL(Product,''),IFNULL(STRING(AdUnitId),''),IFNULL(STRING(AdvertiserId),''),IFNULL(STRING(OrderId),''),IFNULL(STRING(LineItemId),''),IFNULL(STRING(CreativeId),''),IFNULL(Country,''),IFNULL(CreativeSize,''),IFNULL(RequestedAdUnitSizes,''),IFNULL(Format,''),IFNULL(OOP,''),IFNULL(Mode,''),IFNULL(PageType,''),IFNULL(Placement,''),IFNULL(Position,''),IFNULL(STRING(IsCompanion),''),IFNULL(DeviceCategory,'')) key,
    COUNT(*) RowCount
  FROM
    dfpReaderClicks(
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkClicks_319223_20161021],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkBackfillClicks_319223_20161021],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkClicks_319223_20161022],
      [project-id:dfp_data_transfer.dfp_NetworkBackfillClicks_319223_20161022])
  WHERE
    REPLACE(Date,'-','')='20161021'
  GROUP EACH BY
    1 ) _c
ON
  _a.key = _c.key
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    AdUnitId,
    Site,
    AdUnit1Name
  FROM
    [dfp_data_transfer.usr_Ad_Units_Active] ) _d
ON
  _a.AdUnitId = _d.AdUnitId
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: Post your query

Comment: OK, I've added the code with ProjectId changed.

Comment: and your UDF emits how many rows? Do you have any stats about that?

Comment: A single row.  It does a regex on a field to split it into multiple dimensions.

Comment: job id available?

Comment: Sure, this is the one mentioned in the post bqjob_r74c1b05699e79172_00000157f4a17311_1

Comment: This is the one from last night which has given a result with 10% of the rows expected bqjob_r16198859835dd969_0000015804f04803_1

Comment: @AdamSnell Could you please double check the job ids? The second job - at least in our internal statistics - has generated actually more data than the first (both number of rows and number of bytes).

Comment: Apologies, I was looking at the wrong day, it was the day before that's wrong bqjob_r6c743db0b4950669_0000015800498fb4_1

Comment: @AdamSnell Thank you. The two jobs now: bqjob_r74c1b05699e79172_00000157f4a17311_1 and bqjob_r6c743db0b4950669_0000015800498fb4_1 actually select from two different sets of tables (the query in the second one is slightly different that the one in the post.) It is most likely the case that the two data sets do produce different results.

Comment: True, I'm running daily queries to get latest data.  The source tables are stored in different tables so the dates in the FROM statements change but the results should be very consistent.  There is no way one day should have 10% the volume as days around it.